# Font takes a noticeable split second to load. Is there any way around this?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, google-fonts

I'm using a google font in my react project, and whenever I open up my site, there is a very noticeable split second where my text that uses the font initially loads with a seemingly different font, then changes to the correct font right after.

What is happening here? And how do I prevent this from happening?

Loading font in `public/index.html`

```
<link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2family=Bebas+Neue&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet"
/>
```

adding the font to a class in `src/index.css`

```
.bg-header {
  font-family: "Bebas Neue", sans-serif;
  color: darkorange;
  text-decoration: underline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10%;
  left: 5%;
  font-size: 75px;
}
```

html tag in react component

```
<h5 className="bg-header">{getHeader()}</h5>
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use the ‘Preload’ resource hint to tell the browser that we want our font files to start downloading right away, not after the CSS is parsed. This helps loading the font faster.

Most major browsers support preload and other resource hints (Firefox is also currently in development to add this). Adding this to your HTML would look like this:

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" 
  href="<FONT LOCATION>" crossorigin>
```

[Machmetrics](https://www.machmetrics.com/speed-blog/google-fonts-slow-your-site-make-google-fonts-faster/#:%7E:text=Optimize%20Loading,we%20want%20those%20font%20resources.)

Comment: I gave this a shot, but the font just didn't load. I checked out the link you provided, and it seemed that the href in the example points to a local file. I don't think it works with the google api call

Comment: Sorry to hear that. I'll try and find a solution.

Comment: No worries. Appreciate the help though. If I do end up giving in and resorting to downloading the font, I'll use this method.

Comment: @LukeLewis I appreciate your patience. I wish I could do more for you ;)

Answer (score 1):

#### CSS: font-display

If you *really* don't want the font to swap you can use:

```css
body { 
  font-display: block;
}
```

Or probably a more user-friendly way is:

```css
body { 
  font-display: fallback;
}
```

However, this can hurt your rankings in search engines and you should read up on why the fonts are set to swap by default. The default setting for the `font-display` property is `auto`.

You can read about the CSS `font-display` property here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display.

#### Google Fonts display property

In your google fonts import, you can actually specify the font-display setting in the font URL:

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">`

Notice the `display=swap` part of the URL.

#### Other resources

These articles will also be very helpful:

- https://css-tricks.com/font-display-masses/
- https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/02/font-display

Comment: I tried messing around with the display part of the url to change the font-display values. Block seemed to be the most appropriate, as it draws "invisible" text for the block period. However, since my text is underlined, interestingly enough it doesn't get the same "invisible" treatment, and gets drawn out during this block period. Furthermore, I believe the invisible text has larger spacing, resulting in a visible longer underline during the block period. Looks like I might just have to save the font locally.